# Finding an inverse of a matrix in terms of a variable

Tags: matrices

I'm studying some further maths units so that I can be ready for some units I have to take alongside my future PHD. I've been doing well but would love some confirmation with this question.

Let $X =\begin{bmatrix} 6 &  a \\ -2 & -5\end{bmatrix}$ where $a$ is a constant and is not equal to 15.

I am trying to find $X^{-1}$ in terms of $a$. (So the inverse, in terms of $a$)

So I was thinking, by my current understanding, to swap the positions of $a$ and $d$ in this matrix so $6$ and $-5$ are in opposite positions. Then I need to put a negative sign in front of $b$ and $c$, so a becomes $-a$ and $-2$ becomes $+2$.

Then I need to divide everything by the determinant which is $(ad-bc)$.

Am I along the correct lines here?

Then clearly I need to think about taking the a outside of the matrix so that my inverse can be in terms of a.

Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Comment: Could someone possibly show me the final step "in terms of a?" so that I could study this further? I'm just completing the inverse as I type.

Comment: So I have 1/2a-30
 multiplied by (-5 -a)
                      (2   6)

Comment: If I do -5 divided by 2a-30 for example, I'll be needing to remove the a part so that it becomes "in terms of a"

Comment: Can you write the inverse of $X$ using $\LaTeX$, so I can clearly understand what you mean? "In terms of $a$" means that the matrix $X^{-1}$ depends on the parameter $a$.

Comment: Okay sure. 

I'm going to learn the coding later today, I'll get it done.

I'm saying that if I divide the number -5 by 2a-30, that cannot be my final answer for that part.

Comment: Could I remove the factor of a, so that for example I have 1/6th?

Comment: Okay and so if I do this for all of the values, I have an answer in terms of a as I am required.

Comment: So if X + the inverse of X equals the 2x2 identity matrix, how might I work out the value of a in the swiftest possible way?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help so far thanasissdr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37319/discussion-between-thanasissdr-and-i-come-from-a-land-down-under).

Comment: Sure, that'll be helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

According to your sayings matrix $$X^{-1} =\dfrac{1}{2a-30}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix} 
-5 & -a\\
2 & 6
\end{pmatrix} =  
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{-5}{2a-30} & -\dfrac{a}{2a-30}\\
\dfrac{2}{2a-30} & \dfrac{6}{2a-30}
\end{pmatrix},$$ which is written in terms of $a$.

Now, for the part you asked me in the discussion, we want to define $a$ such that 
$$X + X^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Thus,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
6+\dfrac{-5}{2a-30} & a-\dfrac{a}{2a-30}\\[2ex]
-2+\dfrac{2}{2a-30} & -5+\dfrac{6}{2a-30}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

So in order of position in the matix I have
\begin{gather}
a=\frac{1}{2a}-30\\
b=2a-30\\
c=2a-30\\
d=\frac{1}{2a}-30\\
\end{gather}
So I'm assuming I can add the halves to give values of $2a-30$.

Adding all of these together gives me $8a-120$

Therefore I can ascertain that 
\begin{gather}
8a-120=0\\
8a=120\\
a=15.
\end{gather}

Comment: The second answer was me on an anonymous computer. My issue is that the original question states that a cannot be equal to 15 and I'm unsure where to go now.

Comment: Is there any way an answer of 31/2 could be established?

Comment: When we have $\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}$ then it needs to hold:

$\begin{array}{l}
x = A,
y = B,
z = C,
w  = D
\end{array}.$ Try to apply this on the matrix equality in my answer.